# I want to create Arc seek bar in android java , similar to what we see in camera app of our phone

Tags: java, android

I am working on a custom camera app in Android and currently exploring the implementation of a half-circle seek bar for adjusting focus. As a newcomer to Android development, I am seeking guidance on how to approach this task.

Objective:
I want to create a visually appealing half-circle seek bar that users can interact with to adjust the focus in my camera app. The seek bar should be responsive to touch gestures, allowing users to smoothly control the focus within a specified range.

Current Progress:
I have researched existing libraries and found some circular seek bar implementations, but none exactly fit my requirements. I am now attempting to create a custom view that represents a half-circle seek bar.

i have currently added this [UI](https://github.com/eszdman/PhotonCamera/tree/dev/circularbarlib/src/main/java/com/particlesdevs/photoncamera/circularbarlib/ui/views/knobview) in my code but it is not visible can anyone help me